# Generic transposition in python

Tags: python

What is the shortest way, in python, to express transposition with respect to the indexing operator ?

Given some datastructure `x`, I wish to compute `y = transpose(x)`, such that `y[a][b] == x[b][a]`.

When x is, for instance, a list of lists, this can easily be achieved with

```
y = zip(*x)
```

but what if x is not a list, but for instance a dict ?

```
{'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9] }
```

(**EDIT:** for clarification, the input above should give a structure that behaves like:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':7}, {'a':2, 'b':5, 'c':8}, {'a':3, 'b':6, 'c':9}]
```

)

When the member list is known in advance, I can do something like

```
[ {'a': z[0], 'b': z[1], 'c': z[2] } for z in zip(x['a'], x['b'], x['c']) ]
```

which is full of redundancy and inelegant.

I can write a fully generic transpose like so:

```
class Transpose:
    def __init__(self, upper):
        self._upper = upper

    def __getitem__(self, x):
        class Inner:
            def __getitem__(ignore, y):
                return self._upper[y][x]
        return Inner()
```

But that is verbose and very incomplete (doesn't handle iteration properly, among others).

Surely there is an elegant way to achieve this with the standard lib ?

Comment: Always 2D? Will everything in the 2nd dimension be the same (e.g. no lists of a mix of lists and dicts)? *"Surely there is an elegant way to achieve this with the standard lib?"* - were you expecting `transpose_everything`?

Comment: In principle a working 2D version could be applied to deeper levels using successions of map(), and the bubble sort algorithm could be used to generate any permutation of a number of indices, if you really needed that.

Comment: I don't care much about the actual types behind; what is important is reasonable behaviour wrt. the identity i mentioned (y[a][b] == x[b][a])

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data structure is consistent (i.e. all the member lists are the same length), this will work:

```
[{k:v[i] for k,v in x.items()} for i in range(len(x.values()[0]))]
```

You iterate over the indexes in the member lists and create a dictionary that maps each key to the value at that index. Really, all I've done is take your specific example and generalize it. Anytime you notice that you're referencing specific keys in a dictionary, you can usually replace it with an iteration over `for k,v in dict.items()`.

If you can't rely on the consistency of the data structure, then taking the minimum-length list is a decent fix:

```
[{k:v[i] for k,v in x.items()} for i in range(min(len(l) for l in x.values()))]
```

Comment: The case with differing lengths is where the nice behaviour of zip() came into account; my first version also has the advantage of working with generators. I'm still hoping someone can come up with a cleaner and more generic version in the standard lib, but your answer is the best so far.

Comment: What would be the output of a generator that you'd want to support? Dictionary items can't be returned from a generator since dictionaries are non-ordered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking at turning at strictly transposing your list of dicts the way you have, this will work:

```
x = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9] }

[{k:v for k,v in zip(x.keys(),lst)} for lst in x.values()]
```

Results in:

```
[{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 7, 'c': 8, 'b': 9}, {'a': 4, 'c': 5, 'b': 6}]
```

As for something pithy that will do generic transposition on arbitrary data structures, I think it would take quite a bit more work

Comment: This doesn't do what his specific example does, but maybe his example wasn't what he wanted anyway. –

Comment: Thanks too, that isn't what I wanted either. At least you made me discover the dict comprehension :)

Answer (score 0):

For dictionaries specifically, assuming the values are sequences of equal length:

```
import itertools as it
d = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9] }
keys = it.repeat(d.keys())
values = it.izip(*d.values())
dT = [dict(it.izip(*thing)) for thing in it.izip(keys, values)]
```

Passes your identity:

```
#test
for k, v in d.items():
    for n, item in enumerate(v):
        print 'd[{}][{}] == dT[{}][{}] | {}'.format(k, n, n, k, d[k][n] == dT[n][k])
assert all(d[k][n] == dT[n][k] for k, v in d.items() for n, _ in enumerate(v))
```

Will not work if values have different lengths.

Comment: This doesn't do what his specific example does, but maybe his example wasn't what he wanted anyway.

Comment: @Gerrat, Perhaps I misunderstood.